# Create Table Syntax Error in Hive

Tags: hive, hiveql, apache-hive

I am trying to create a table in hive using following query:

```
create table customers(Cust_ID INT, Cust_Name STRING, Dealer_ID INT, Country STRING, State STRING, City STRING, ZipCode INT)
    row format delimited
    fields terminated by ';'
    stored as textfile;
```

but i'm getting the following error:

```
FAILED: Parse Error: line 0:-1 mismatched input '<EOF>' expecting StringLiteral in table row format's field separator
```

i have created previously transactions table with same syntax and it had worked out just fine..but somehow i think m making some syntatical error. plz help.

Answer (score 0):

Try escaping ';' by adding '\' os your query will look as follow:

```
create table customers(Cust_ID INT, Cust_Name STRING, Dealer_ID INT, Country STRING, State STRING, City STRING, ZipCode INT)
    row format delimited
    fields terminated by '\;'
    stored as textfile;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using the OCT \073 instead of ';'
Example:

```
row format delimited fields terminated by '\073'
```